# Topology from basis sets of the form $(, )$ or $(, ) − $.

Tags: general-topology

> Let $\Bbb{R}_{har}$ be the set $\Bbb{R}$ with a topology whose basis is all sets of the form $(, )$ or $(, ) \setminus $, where $ = \{\frac1n\}_{∈ℕ}$ and $,  ∈ ℝ$. Verify that these sets forms the basis for a topology.

I feel like the statement here is a bit problematic what do they mean by sets of the form $(, )$ or $(, ) − $? Is this the same as $\mathcal{B}= \{(a,b) \mid a,b \in \Bbb R\} \cup \{(a,b) \setminus H \mid a,b \in \Bbb R, H = \{\frac1n\} \}$? Also how can you take away a real number $\frac1n$ from an interval $(a,b)$? Is $(a,b) \setminus H$ the same as $(a-\frac1n, b-\frac1n)$?

I have that $\bigcup_{j} (j, j+1)$ covers $\Bbb R$ which is the first condition for a set to be a basis for topology. But should I now consider also $(a,b) \setminus H$ somehow?

Comment: $H = \{1, 1/2, 1/3, \cdots\}$ is a set, and $(a, b)-H$ just mean $\{x\in (a, b) : x\notin H\}$.

Comment: You can also describe this space as having all intervals plus $\Bbb R\setminus H$ as a subbase. Or as the smallest topology that is finer than the usual topology and has $H$ as a closed subset.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

You proved the first axiom for a collection $\mathcal B$ to be the basis of a topology.

Define $\mathcal B_1 = \{(a,b) \mid a \lt b\}$ and $\mathcal B_2 = \{(a,b)  \setminus H\mid a \lt b\}$.

Take $U,V \in \mathcal B = \mathcal B_1 \cup \mathcal B_2$ and denote $W = U \cap V$. You'll have to write what $W$ is depending on the cases $U,V \in \mathcal B_1$ or if one of $U,V$ belongs to $\mathcal B_2$. With this, verifying the second axiom for a basis of topology is quite immediate.